# FCM Registration working in emulator, but not on real device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working with the following dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
```

However, I tried compiling 10.0.1 versions of these three earlier which required me to download some updated libraries.

FCM registration then failed on my emulator - nothing was being stored in my remote database - so I moved back to 9.4.0 which is when registration began working again, however instead of
`String token = myInstanceIDListenerService.getToken();` returning the FCM token, it returned an array like: `{"token":xxxxxxx, "app_version":xx}`.

So I began parsing through this array to get the token. This fixed everything on my emulator, however registration is not working on my phone.

Comment: Sorry. Can you elaborate what isn't working when you test on an actual device? It's a bit unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. The issue was that my Google API's were not fully up to date, so I updated them via the SDK Manager in Android Studio.

Comment: I'm having this issue. How did you get it to work on a real device?